# Remove part of text value with powershell

Tags: powershell, site-column

I am using PowerShell to copy the value from one column to another in a document library.
The source column is the name field. So far I have this script and it works fine.

```
$web =  Get-SPWeb -Identity http://siteURL
$lista = $web.Lists["test"]
$items = $lista.items
foreach ($item in $items) {
   $value = $item["Name"]
   $item["other column"] = $value
   $item.update()
}
$lista.update()
```

The only bit I am missing is the ability to remove the file extension from the text value of the name column.
Do if the value of the name column is "myFile.pdf" then I need the value of other column to be "myFile"
Can I split on something?
I am 99% certain there will be no filenames with a "." in them other than the one that separates the name and the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is just another .NET language. You can use methods you would normally use in C# or VB. So the simplest solution is:

```
$item["other column"] = $value.Split('.')[0]
```

But you are not limited to `String` methods. You can call static method of `System.IO.Path` class this way:

```
$item["other column"] = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($value)
```

Of course you should do some required `$null` checks first.

Comment: Thanks I did it like this... apologise for the formatting but everytime I hit enter or shift enter the comment is submitted  rather than a line break........
 $value = $item["Name"]
     $splitvalue = $value.Split(".")
            $item["Asset ID"] = $splitvalue[0]